# How to add a classname to the DOM on an if condition in ExtJS(similar to adding class in Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, extjs

I want to add a class to add some styles to the element using ExtJs very similar to the way we do in Jquery-`$(".container").addClass("sub-cont")`
Js:

```
function chart(data){
  if(data.type=="aaa"){
     //add the class using Ext.js like in jquery:$(".highcharts").addClass("sub-highcharts")
  }else{
   return false;
  }
});
```

any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way

```
     var dom = Ext.select('..highcharts').elements[0];  
     Ext.fly(dom).addCls('sub-highcharts');
```

Comment: That's fairly convoluted. `Ext.select('.highcharts').addCls('sub-highcharts');` will do.